# How to save a statsmodels formula and params as text for later use making predictions?

Tags: python, regression, curve-fitting, statsmodels

Statsmodels in python gives a nice way to do linear fits with various R style formula, and make predictions based on the results. Everything needed to make predictions should be contained in just the formula and the list of fit parameters. I'd like to save just those (e.g. in a text config file, or another script, so no pickles etc.).

So, given just the original formula and the fit parameters is there any easy way to reconstruct a model and make predictions?

I'm also open to alternatives to `statsmodels`.

Example:

```python
import numpy as np                                                                                                                                                                                      
import statsmodels.formula.api as sm                                                                                                                                                                    
import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                     
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# Example data                                                                                                                                                                                          
x = np.mgrid[-1:1:10000j]                                                                                                                                                                               
y = np.sin(x*5)                                                                                                                                                                                         
z = 1+2*x+3*y+4*x*y+5*x**2+6*y**2+(np.random.rand(len(x))-.5)                                                                                                                                           
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.c_[x,y,z], columns = ['x','y','z'])                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# Fit the data                                                                                                                                                                                          
formula = 'z ~ 1+x*y+I(x**2)+I(y**2)'                                                                                                                                                                   
result = sm.ols(formula, data=df).fit()                                                                                                                                                                 
print(result.summary())                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# Save formula and params in text freindly way                                                                                                                                                          
saved_formula = 'z ~ ' + '+'.join(result.params.index).replace('Intercept','1') # (is this necessary?)                                                                                                  
saved_params = result.params.values                                                                                                                                                                     
print(saved_formula)                                                                                                                                                                                    
print(saved_params)                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# Load the formula/params                                                                                                                                                                               
model = result.predict # <-- REPLACE - generate new model using saved_formula, saved_params                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# Apply fit to new data                                                                                                                                                                                 
dfnew = pd.DataFrame(data = np.c_[x+1,y], columns = ['x','y'])                                                                                                                                          
znew = model(dfnew)                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                                                                                                        
# Plot - just for fun                                                                                                                                                                                   
plt.figure(1);plt.clf()                                                                                                                                                                                 
plt.plot(df.x, z, label='data')                                                                                                                                                                         
plt.plot(df.x, model(df), label='model')                                                                                                                                                                
plt.show()                                                                                                                                                                                              
plt.legend()
```

Output (the text to be saved/used later):

```
z ~ 1+x+y+x:y+I(x ** 2)+I(y ** 2)
[1.00604349 2.00219577 3.00889718 3.99726889 5.00210454 5.99458244]
```

**Edit:**
I tried creating a dummy model with fake data to get the object with 'predict' capability (e.g. `result.predict()`), then switch out the fit parameters (e.g. `result.params = saved_params` or `result.pvalues = saved_params`), but unfortunately that didn't work. Whatever params the model is actually using to make the predictions seem to be not exposed/editable?

[image: Plot of fit data]

Comment: I can help you with code to write the formula and the list of parameters to a text config file, and to read the values back from that file, but as far as I know it may not be possible to reconstruct the model object on which you can call the `.predict()` method from just those two things.  You also need access to the instance of the RegressionResults class, created by calling the `.fit()` method.  That instance can be saved to pickle, but that's not what you want.

Comment: Thanks but the saving/loading part is the easy part. It's just figuring out how to use the fit parameters again that's difficult. I can always hard code my own function for a particular set of parameters but I was hoping to keep the convenience of the `statsmodels` functions, so the function string can be edited and saved along with the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I've been digging a little deeper and it looks like `statsmodels` uses `patsy` for the function language and generating arrays to do matrix math. So, a 'predict' function can be reimplemented by hand with patsy like this:

```
# Save formula and params in text freindly way                                                                                        
#saved_formula = 'z ~ ' + '+'.join(result.params.index).replace('Intercept','1') # (is this necessary?)                               
saved_formula = formula                                                                                                               
saved_params = result.params.to_dict()                                                                                                
                                                                                                                                      
# Load the formula/params                                                                                                             
import patsy                                                                                                                          
def predict(data, formula) :                                                                                                          
    formula_rhs = formula.split('~')[1].strip()                                                                                       
    x_data = patsy.dmatrix(formula_rhs, data=df)                                                                                      
    ordered_terms = x_data.design_info.term_names                                                                                     
    ordered_params = list(map(saved_params.get, ordered_terms))                                                                       
    return x_data @ ordered_params                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                      
model = lambda x : predict(x, saved_formula)
```

This could be simplified a bit, but I was worried about the order of parameters potentially being different in the reconstructed matrix as opposed to the original. Not sure if this would actually be a concern, but I think with what I did it is not. I changed the parameters to be saved as a dictionary. The new data matrix is produced, then after I know what order the columns are in I extract the parameters from the saved parameter dict in that order.

The last line of the predict function is the predict step. The only reason I needed the rest is to work with configurable linear models (i.e. not just parameters for a model). If you know you have a particular set model you could simplify this.

Going to and from text is easy enough with the parameters in that form. E.g.

```
import json
saved_params_string = json.dumps(saved_params)
json.loads(saved_params_string)
```

The `formula` and `saved_params_string` strings can then be saved to or loaded from a config file or hard coded as desired.

The actual saving to a config file can be done easily enough with `json` or `yaml` - I'll probably use the later.